# How do i increase the RAM Of my Laptop?

Tags: laptop

I have a Lenovo ThinkPad Laptop with 8 GB RAM, but now it's not enough for me. I want to increase the RAM of my laptop, but I don't know how to do it. If anyone knows, please tell me what the process is for this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Have you tried to google this? What did your research turn up? Your question is unanswerable because not all laptops have upgradable RAM and we don't know which model you have.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check your laptop can fit more RAM, or that a higher capacity module is available.
2. Buy more of the correct RAM modules.
3. Remove the old RAM module(s) and replace with the new.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

This webpage will explain to you how to find the maximum supported RAM.

https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/ht504725-where-to-find-the-maximum-supported-ram-information

You can use crucial.com to figure out which RAM is compatible.